# Inserting rows of zeros at specific places along the rows of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a two column numpy array. I want to go through each row of the 2nd column, and take the difference between each set of 2 numbers (9.6-0, 19.13-9.6, etc). If the difference is > 15, I want to insert a row of 0s for both columns. I really only need to end up with values in the first column (I only need the second to determine where to put 0s), so if it's easier to split them up that would be fine.

This is my input array:

```
 [[0.00 0.00]
 [1.85 9.60]
 [2.73 19.13]
 [0.30 28.70]
 [2.64 38.25]
 [2.29 47.77]
 [2.01 57.28]
 [2.61 66.82]
 [2.20 76.33]
 [2.49 85.85]
 [2.55 104.90]
 [2.65 114.47]
 [1.79 123.98]
 [2.86 133.55]]
```

and it should turn into:

```
 [[0.00 0.00]
 [1.85 9.60]
 [2.73 19.13]
 [0.30 28.70]
 [2.64 38.25]
 [2.29 47.77]
 [2.01 57.28]
 [2.61 66.82]
 [2.20 76.33]
 [2.49 85.85]
 [0.00 0.00]
 [2.55 104.90]
 [2.65 114.47]
 [1.79 123.98]
 [2.86 133.55]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input array, here's a vectorized approach based on initialization with zeros -

```
# Get indices at which such diff>15 occur 
cut_idx = np.where(np.diff(A[:,1]) > 15)[0]

# Initiaize output array
out = np.zeros((A.shape[0]+len(cut_idx),2),dtype=A.dtype)

# Get row indices in the output array at which rows from A are to be inserted.
# In other words, avoid rows to be kept as zeros. Finally, insert rows from A.
idx = ~np.in1d(np.arange(out.shape[0]),cut_idx + np.arange(1,len(cut_idx)+1))
out[idx] = A
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [50]: A  # Different from the one posted in question to show variety
Out[50]: 
array([[   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   1.85,    0.6 ],
       [   2.73,   19.13],
       [   2.2 ,   76.33],
       [   2.49,   85.85],
       [   2.55,  104.9 ],
       [   2.65,  114.47],
       [   1.79,  163.98],
       [   2.86,  169.55]])

In [51]: out
Out[51]: 
array([[   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   1.85,    0.6 ],
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   2.73,   19.13],
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   2.2 ,   76.33],
       [   2.49,   85.85],
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   2.55,  104.9 ],
       [   2.65,  114.47],
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   1.79,  163.98],
       [   2.86,  169.55]])
```

Comment: hum it's not the wanted output.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Well I changed the input array to show more variety in there.

Comment: Well, we can't ask the OPs to generate an example and the desired output and then just change it :). (I've done the same before). Upvote for the elegant solution, though I'm still working through it.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Yeah, OP sometimes produce oversimplified cases and I tend to modify those for my sample runs so as to make sure more varying cases could be handled. I think it's safer that way and hopefully askers would learn something from those when posting their next questions on SO :)

Comment: Plus the OP example can't be copy-n-pasted - it's missing the necessary commas.  While it is nice to test against the example, it also nice in this case to test for more than one fill slot.  The `Colonel's` answer only handles one slot.

Comment: yes, good call! I do need it to work for more than one slot. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

and FYI I did copy/paste but from the terminal printed output

Comment: @Maria But the sample input array posted in the question doesn't have elements separated by commas, so we can't copy n paste that into our Python environments as such. Instead you can print the array with this command : `print repr(A)`, where `A` is the input array and that will print out with commas, which you can copy n paste for your future questions. Good luck with them on Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do in a one liner using `ediff1d` , `argmax` and `insert` from `numpy`:

```
np.insert(arr, np.argmax(np.append(False, np.ediff1d(arr[:,1])>15)), 0, axis=0)

#array([[   0.  ,    0.  ],
#       [   1.85,    9.6 ],
#       [   2.73,   19.13],
#       [   0.3 ,   28.7 ],
#       [   2.64,   38.25],
#       [   2.29,   47.77],
#       [   2.01,   57.28],
#       [   2.61,   66.82],
#       [   2.2 ,   76.33],
#       [   2.49,   85.85],
#       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
#       [   2.55,  104.9 ],
#       [   2.65,  114.47],
#       [   1.79,  123.98],
#       [   2.86,  133.55]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[[0.00, 0.00],
 [1.85, 9.60],
 [2.73, 19.13],
 [0.30, 28.70],
 [2.64, 38.25],
 [2.29, 47.77],
 [2.01, 57.28],
 [2.61, 66.82],
 [2.20, 76.33],
 [2.49, 85.85],
 [2.55, 104.90],
 [2.65, 114.47],
 [1.79, 123.98],
 [2.86, 133.55]]

i=0
while i <len(a)-1:
    if (a[i+1][1]-a[i][1])>15:
        a.insert(i+1,[0,0])
        i=i+1
    i=i+1    

for line in a :
    print line
```

output:

```
[0.0, 0.0]
[1.85, 9.6]
[2.73, 19.13]
[0.3, 28.7]
[2.64, 38.25]
[2.29, 47.77]
[2.01, 57.28]
[2.61, 66.82]
[2.2, 76.33]
[2.49, 85.85]
[0, 0]
[2.55, 104.9]
[2.65, 114.47]
[1.79, 123.98]
[2.86, 133.55]
```

Comment: He does say that this is an array (and it displays without the commas), so your list operation won't work (no insert method).  But for modest size lists,this is probably faster than a 'pure' numpy operation.  And clearer.

Comment: Ty, good point. He would have to back convert to list, which is non-trivial when nested I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here's right algorithm:

```
arr = [ ... ]
result = []
result.append(arr[0])
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i][1] - arr[i-1][1] > 15:
        result.append([0.0,0.0])
    result.append(arr[i])

print(result)
```

Comment: hmmm, it doesn't seem to be adding 0s. also `math.abs` gave me an error, so I replaced it with just `abs`.

the output is 

    [array([2.73, 19.13]), array([0.30, 28.70]), array([2.64, 38.25]), array([2.29, 47.77]), array([2.01, 57.28]), array([2.61, 66.82]), array([2.20, 76.33]), array([2.49, 85.85]), array([2.55, 104.90]), array([2.65, 114.47]), array([1.79, 123.98]) ...

Comment: I think i give you totally wrong algorythm. I will edit them now.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner that can handle more than one fill slot.  Here I'm testing it on the OP example, with one modified value.

```
In [70]: np.insert(a, np.where(np.diff(a[:,1])>15)[0]+2,0, axis=0)


In [71]: Out[70]: 
array([[   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   1.85,    9.6 ],
       [   2.73,   19.13],
       [   0.3 ,   28.7 ],
       [   2.64,   38.25],
       [   2.29,  140.  ],   # modified
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   2.01,   57.28],
       [   2.61,   66.82],
       [   2.2 ,   76.33],
       [   2.49,   85.85],
       [   2.55,  104.9 ],
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   2.65,  114.47],
       [   1.79,  123.98],
       [   2.86,  133.55]])
```

The use of `where` instead of `argmax` (`Colonel's` answer) handles more than one slot.  The `+2` is required because `diff` is one short, and we are inserting after.  `ediff1d` has more options for handling the end points.

`np.insert` has various strategies for filling.  In this case it probably is doing something similar to `Divakar's` answer - create an `out`, and copy values to the correct slots.

Another answer uses `np.abs()`.  That might be needed, but in my example that would add another `0` row, after the `140` drops back to `57`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if `numpy` didn't have some native methods for doing this sort of thing but I think this will work too:

```
i = 1
while i < len(lst):
    if abs(lst[i][1] - lst[i-1][1]) > 15:
        lst[i] = [0.0, 0.0]
        # uncomment to change only the second column
        # lst[i][1] = 0.0
        i += 1
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
array([[   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   1.85,    9.6 ],
       [   2.73,   19.13],
       [   0.3 ,   28.7 ],
       [   2.64,   38.25],
       [   2.29,   47.77],
       [   2.01,   57.28],
       [   2.61,   66.82],
       [   2.2 ,   76.33],
       [   2.49,   85.85],
       [   2.55,  104.9 ],
       [   2.65,  114.47],
       [   1.79,  123.98],
       [   2.86,  133.55]])
>>> 
>>> i = 1
>>> while i < len(lst):
...     if abs(lst[i][1] - lst[i-1][1]) > 15:
...         lst[i] = [0.0, 0.0]
...         i += 1
...     i += 1
... 
>>> lst
array([[   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   1.85,    9.6 ],
       [   2.73,   19.13],
       [   0.3 ,   28.7 ],
       [   2.64,   38.25],
       [   2.29,   47.77],
       [   2.01,   57.28],
       [   2.61,   66.82],
       [   2.2 ,   76.33],
       [   2.49,   85.85],
       [   0.  ,    0.  ],
       [   2.65,  114.47],
       [   1.79,  123.98],
       [   2.86,  133.55]])
>>>
```